# override OAuth2 token endpoint request .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, ebay-api

I'm trying to use Ebay's OAuth2 flow in .net core 2 by registering the authentication middleware.    The authorization succeeded, but getting this error when the middleware is processing the token request (after receiving code from authorization service).

```
Exception: OAuth token endpoint failure: Status: BadRequest;Headers: 
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Tue, 27 Mar 2018 14:42:38 GMT
...  
Body: {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"request is missing a 
required parameter or malformed."};
```

eBay's requirements for the access token request are

```
HTTP method: POST  
URL (Sandbox): https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token
HTTP headers:  
  Content-Type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded  
  Authorization = Basic 'B64-encoded-oauth-credentials'

Request body (wrapped for readability):  
grant_type=authorization_code&  
code=<authorization-code-value>&  
redirect_uri='RuName-value'
```

seems like the request token is not in the right format, wherein the code can I  format the required body and headers for the token request.

attaching my code [my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXtch.png)

code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
            options.SslPort = 44321;
        });

        services.AddAntiforgery(
            options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "_af";
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";
            });

        // authentication middleware
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Ebay";
        })
    .AddCookie()
    .AddOAuth("Ebay", options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = "my-client-id";
        options.ClientSecret = "my-secret";
        options.CallbackPath = "/signin-Ebay";

        options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://signin.ebay.com/authorize?redirect_uri=my-uri";
        options.TokenEndpoint = "https://api.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token";
        options.Scope.Add("https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope");

        options.Events = new OAuthEvents
        {
            OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
            {
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
                request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);

                var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, 
                                                                    context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var user = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

                context.RunClaimActions(user);
            }
        };
    });


    }
```

Comment: Can you please add your code to your question? Screenshots are an awful medium for grokking code.

Comment: added the code.

Comment: grant_type=authorization_code to /token endpoint?

Comment: yup, that's what the eBay's guys decided to do...

Comment: ...with the authorization code attached?

Comment: no, the code is in a separate property

Comment: Change it to grant_type=token and run it through to try. It makes no sense to send an authorization code to get an authorization code.

Comment: I don't know how can i override this property in the code?

Comment: Looking at docs. That does look right. Can you add your sent message  (in fiddler or whatever you prefer) so we can look at the sent message for issues?

Comment: I know what the issues are: 1. it sends the client id and client secret as part of the data form instead of authorization header. 2.doen't contain the RuName in the form. the question is how to override the middleware implementation so it will send the id and secret as header...

Comment: You're sending a get instead of a post, and you're not sending the form body. You also forgot to set UserInformationEndpoint.

Comment: when capturing the request on fiddler, i noticed it was a Post not a get... i don't send the form body its implemented in the AddOauth function implementation. the question is how do i override their implementation add send a custom body form...

Comment: I encounter the same problem, did you find out how to do this?